# How to open 4 netrw file explors simultaneously in format [:][:] (each dot being a netrw file explorer pane)

Tags: vim, neovim, netrw

In vim or neovim I can do the following

:e.|vs.|vs.|sp.

To open various netrw file explorers simultaneously. The command above results in the following layout:

```
|netrw0|netrw1|netrw2|
|      |      |netrw3|
```

Now what I want to accomplish is a oneliner which results in the following layout:

```
|netrw0|netrw2|
|netrw1|netrw3|
```

I'm not sure if this is possible, ofcourse I can switch panes to get the above result, however that is not what I want because the thing I'm actually doing is creating a function in my vimrc which I link to a function key, that way I can press a function key and open the desired splitted file browsing layout.

ps. in my .init.vim (I'm using neovim), I have "set splitright" in order to open vertical splitted windows by default on the right side.

Comment: Turned out easier than I thought and I've discovered the solution quite quickly, in the time that I've answered my own question multiple correct answers arrived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the command :wincmd it is possible to switch panes from the command line. The following oneliner result in the desired layout:

:e.|vs.|wincmd h|wincmd h|sp.|wincmd l|sp.

Answer (score 1):

Check the help for `:vertical`. There are a lot of commands to switch position of windows at their creation. This one is a possible solution for your case:

```
:e 0 | sp 1 | bo vs 2 | sp 3
```

*(I changed the `.` to numbers for demonstration purposes only).*

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
:vsplit . | split | wincmd w | edit . | split
```

Answer (score 0):

in vim the following works:

```
:e.|sp|vsp|wincmd j|vsp
```